# Cosmos DB REST API authorisation header won't allow me to replace a document

Tags: rest, azure-cosmosdb

I'm writing a PowerShell script to read and modify documents in a Cosmos DB collection. For read I'm using the [GET endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/get-a-document), and for modification I'm using the [PUT endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/replace-a-document).

Read works fine, but for modification I'm getting 401 with no helpful explanation.

Here is the code I'm using the generate the authorisation header, which, as I say, works fine for read:

```
Function New-CosmosAuthorisationToken {
    Param([String]$Verb, [String]$ResourceType, [String]$ResourceId, [String]$Date, [String]$Key, [String]$KeyType, [String]$TokenVersion)
    $convertedKey = [Convert]::FromBase64String($Key)
    $hmacSha256 = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
    $hmacSha256.Key = $convertedKey
    $payload = [String]::Format([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InstalledUICulture, "{0}`n{1}`n{2}`n{3}`n{4}`n",$verb.ToLowerInvariant(),$resourceType.ToLowerInvariant(),$resourceId,$date.ToLowerInvariant(),"") 
    $hashPayload = $hmacSha256.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($payload))
    $signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($hashPayload)
    $header = [String]::Format([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InstalledUICulture,"type={0}&ver={1}&sig={2}",$KeyType,$TokenVersion,$Signature)
    [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($header)
}
```

When I generate the token for modification, I am:

- Setting the $Verb parameter in the function invocation to PUT
- Using a read-write (as opposed to read only) access key

The URI I'm using for the modification exactly matches that for a successful modification done in the Azure portal (you can inspect them using the browser dev tools).

The headers I'm including in the request are:

- Authorization: (the token)
- Content-Type: (application/json, as opposed to application/query+json for the read call)
- x-ms-version: (2018-12-31)
- x-ms-date: (UTC now, exact same date as used to generate the authorisation header token)
- x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey: the document's partition key, on its own in an array

Can anyone imagine why I'd be getting 401 back from the REST API?

Comment: COuld you please provide a sample of your payload?

Comment: @JimXu I assume you're asking for the payload component of the authorisation token. This looks like:

put\ndocs\n\ndbs/mydatabaes/colls/mycollection\ntue, 16 feb 2021 12:32:22 gmt\n\n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I'm now updating a specific, named document, the `ResourceId` passed into the function to generate the authorisation header token should identity the specific document, e.g.

```
dbs/mydatabase/colls/mycollection/docs/mydocumentid
```